# On button click fade div in, otherwise fade in after x seconds

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to fade in a div after x seconds, but if a button is clicked, fade in right away or make the delay sooner. However, the button click is not overriding the default.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {             
      $('#thepopupdiv').delay(12000).fadeIn(700);

      $("#skipIntroBTN").click(function() {
           $('#thepopupdiv').fadeIn(700); 
      });
 });
```

/**** UPDATE ****/
Thanks to @Nenad Vracar I got this working except for one bug. If you wait, the popup loads. But if you click the link, the popup loads, but when you close the popup, it loads again. It shouldn't load again if opened with the link.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/9d7sua0h/12/

Comment: Put up a fiddle for easily checking the code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `setTimeout` here

```js
var fade = function() {
  $('div').fadeIn(700);
}
$('button').click(function() {
  fade()
});

setTimeout(fade, 12000);
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLick</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Only thing I realized is I have an X button in the popup div to close the popup using fadeOut(). When closed the popup still comes back up after 12 seconds. Is there a way to have it cancel out the timeout so it doesn't come back up.

Comment: Here's my fiddle. Notice that when you load the popup and then close it fast, it still opens again. I want it not to open again if you clicked to open it: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/9d7sua0h/12/

Answer (score 0):

The `.delay()` function in jQuery operates as a queue, and cannot be cancelled once it is called.  It is recommended to use `setTimeout` in cases where you want to override delay logic instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
      $("#skipIntroBTN").click(function() {
        $('#thepopupdiv').fadeIn(700); 
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#thepopupdiv').fadeIn(700);
      }, 12000);
 });
```

You can check the [.delay() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) for more information on this limitation and use cases.

**Update**

Regarding your update on the question, you've got the right idea, but in the wrong place.  If you move the check for the skipped class into the `fade()` function, you'll be able to stop the reappearing of the div.  Currently, you have that check around your `setTimeout` call, which (unless you're a superhumanly fast clicker) will always pass that skipped class check.  Trying the below update should fix the problem:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   //load popup

   var fade = function() {
     // move the hasClass check into the fade function
     if (!$('#thepopupdiv').hasClass('skipped'))
       $('#thepopupdiv').fadeIn(700);
   }

   $("#skipIntroBTN").click(function() {
     $('#thepopupdiv').fadeIn(700).addClass('skipped');
     fade();
   });

   setTimeout(fade, 5000);

   $(".closeit").click(function() {
     $("#thepopupdiv").fadeOut(0001);
   });

 });
```

```css
#thepopupdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#thepopupdiv a {
  color: #fff;
}

#skipIntroBTN {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="skipIntroBTN">
  <a href="#">click here for popup</a>
</div>

<div id="thepopupdiv">
  <a href="#" class="closeit">click to close popup NOW</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment below the correct answer but I don't have comment privileges. lol I think in your comment you said there is a button that fades the div back out but then the timer brings it back after it expires.

There is another JavaScript function called clearTimeout() that can stop the initial timer if the button is clicked

Here is a working Fiddle of what I believe you are asking for https://jsfiddle.net/81u97ux9/1/

HTML

```
<div id="thepopupdiv" style="display: none">
    <p>
        This Is a hidden Div
        <button id="fadeOut">
        Fade Out
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
<button id="skipIntroBTN">
    Press me
</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
  var fade = function() {
    $('#thepopupdiv').fadeIn(700);
  }
  var timer = setTimeout(fade, 10000)
  $("#skipIntroBTN").click(function() {
       fade(); 
       clearTimeout(timer);
  });
  $("#fadeOut").click(function() {
       $('#thepopupdiv').fadeOut(700);

  });
});
```